# Can I sort Order Items by categories in Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to sort items on the Woocommerce notification emails by categories, as by default they are sorted by the order the customer picks them and add them to the cart. Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a solution added to the email-order-items.php - this adds the categories to the admin email and sorts by using the category (I have categories with numbers that relate to warehouse location - so to have all the same locations together really helps the client pick the order.)

the template is the older version but it still works

```
//**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php.
*
* HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
* (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
* maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
* happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
* the readme will list any important changes.
*
* @see      https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
* @author       WooThemes
* @package  WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
* @version     3.0.0
*/

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
global  $woocommerce , $wpdb;

$c1 = $wpdb->get_results("select t1.order_item_name,t1.order_item_id,t5.name,t2.meta_value from wp_woocommerce_order_items as t1 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as t2 ON t1.order_item_id = t2.order_item_id LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as t3 ON t2.meta_value = t3.object_id LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t4 ON t3.term_taxonomy_id = t4.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN wp_terms as t5 ON t4.term_id = t5.term_id where t1.order_id = '".$order->id."' and t1.order_item_type='line_item' and t2.meta_key='_product_id' and t4.taxonomy='product_cat' ORDER BY `t5`.`name` ASC");
$array = array();
foreach($c1 as $data)
{
  if (!in_array($data->order_item_id , $array)) {
  $array[] = $data->order_item_id;
 }

}

//foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
foreach($array as $newdata) :
$item = $order->get_item($newdata);
if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

            // Show title/image etc
            if ( $show_image ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' ) ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Product image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-' . ( is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right' ) . ': 10px;" /></div>', $item );
            }

            // Product name
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false );

            // SKU
            if ( $show_sku && is_object( $product ) && $product->get_sku() ) {
                echo ' (#' . $product->get_sku() . ')';
            }

            // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

            wc_display_item_meta( $item );

            if ( $show_download_links ) {
                wc_display_item_downloads( $item );
            }

            // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

            // get category for admin email only
           if( $sent_to_admin ) {
                echo get_the_term_list( $product->id, 'product_cat', __( 'Categories', 'woocommerce' ).': ', ', ' );
            }

        ?></td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ); ?></td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

    if ( $show_purchase_note && is_object( $product ) && ( $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note() ) ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to WooCommerce > Settings in your WordPress admin. On the Products tab, under the Display settings,change the Default Product Sorting.

Comment: Option for sorting the products by categories is not available there.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Order by" in your sql query.